# I need to keep anything between a certain pattern

Tags: regex

I'm working with ~1800 whole genome sequences of SARS-CoV-2 and I want to keep only the "EPI_ISL_NC045512" pattern, which is between two "|".
This would be my string:

```
>New|hCoV-19/Belize/BZ-CML-TCMC-BZ002-0820/2020|EPI_ISL_NC045512|2020-08-12NC045512
actcacgcagtataattaataactaattactgtcgttgacaggacacgagtaactcgtctatcttctgcaggctgcttacggtttcgtccgtg
```

I would need to also keep the ">"
I tried (>)(.+)([EPI.+])(.+) but it didn't work

Comment: Which programming language are you using? Or is this just `sed`?

Answer (score 0):

A simple one could be this one: `|(EPI([A-Z0-9_]+))|`

Assuming only `A-Z` `0-9` and `_` on your pattern, the result is in group 1 (surrounded by parenthesis).

Answer (score 0):

You could use 2 capture groups if you want to keep `>` in a group and `EPI_ISL_NC045512` in a group

```php
(>)[^>]*\|(EPI[^|]*)\|
```

- `(>)` Capture `>` in **group 1**
- `[^>]*\|` Optionally match any char except `>` and then match `|`
- `(EPI[^|]*)` Capture EPI followed by any char except `|` in **group 2**
- `\|` Match `|`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kUT3OX/1)